# How to search a record?

Tags: position, rpgle

How to search or go to the position by field in RPGLE?

This is my screen :

[image]

Let say, I want to go to position of date 02/06/2016, and enter at the 'Position to..' field, supposedly the cursor will go to 02/06/2021 and the record after that.

But seems like I have an infinite loop. When I debug, I realize that the Date is 02/06/2021 and didn't go to the next date after that. What should I do? Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Date       reade   curexg
            dou     %eof   
            
            select
   exgcod  wheneq 'USD'
            move   exgrat   usd
   exgcod  wheneq 'GBP'
            move   exgrat   gbp
   exgcod  wheneq 'EUR'
            move   exgrat   eur     
   exgcod  wheneq 'AUD'
            move   exgrat   aud 
   exgcod  wheneq 'SGD'
            move   exgrat   sgd 
            endsl  
    Date    reade curexg 

            enddo
```

This looks like an infinite loop to me. You read your file with a reade(read equal) but you never update your Date variable, you read the same record over and over again, not reaching %eof.

Answer (score 0):

the loop within a loop would be too complicated for me.  An RPG procedure which returns each exchange rate of a specific exchange date would help simplify.

```
** ------------------------ curexg_readExchangeRates --------------
pcurexg_readExchangeRates...                                       
p                 b                                                
dcurexg_readExchangeRates...                                       
d                 pi                                               
d outUsd                         5p 2                              
d outGbp                         5p 2                              
d outEur                         5p 2                              
d outAud                         5p 2                              
d outSgd                         5p 2                              
d inExgDat                        d   const                        
                                                                   
 /free                                                             
      outUsd      = 0 ;                                            
      outGbp      = 0 ;                                            
      outEur      = 0 ;                                            
      outAud      = 0 ;                                            
      outSgd      = 0 ;                                            
      setll       ( inExgDat ) curexg ;                            
      dow         1 = 1 ;                                          
      reade       ( inExgDat ) curexg ;                            
      if          %eof ;                                           
      leave ; 
      endif ;                     
                                  
      if          exgcod = 'USD' ;
      outUsd      = exgrat ;      
      elseif      exgcod = 'GBP' ;
      outGbp      = exgrat ;      
      elseif      exgcod = 'EUR' ;
      outEur      = exgrat ;      
      elseif      exgcod = 'AUD' ;
      outAud      = exgrat ;      
      elseif      exgcod = 'SGD' ;
      outSgd      = exgrat ;      
      endif ;                     
      enddo ;                     
                                  
      return ;                    
 /end-free                        
p                 e
```

then you can have a simple loop that reads exchange rate dates from a starting date:

```
     dow         1 = 1 ;                               
     setll       ( startDate ) curexg ;                
     read        curexg ;                              
     if          %eof ;                                
     leave ;                                           
     endif ;                                           
     cur_date    = exgdat ;                            
     curexg_readExchangeRates( usd: gbp: eur: aud: sgd:
                               cur_date ) ;            
                                                       
 // write exchange rates of current date to subfile.   
     write       sflrec ;                              
                                                       
 // advance to next exchange rate date                 
     setgt       ( cur_date ) curexg ;                 
     read        curexg ;                              
     if          %eof ;                                
     leave ;                                           
     endif ;                                           
     startDate   = exgdat ;                            
     enddo ;
```

Comment: I see, but how to make the cursor go to the search date?

Comment: setll on the search date ( or start date ), no ?

Comment: I know that setll on the search date, but will the cursor position will go to that date?

Comment: Okay I think i got it now, but my problem now is, I cannot page up before the search date. I think that is my concern now. What should I do?

Comment: paging up is combination of `SETLL` to position before the set of `EXGDAT` records, and then `READP` to read the last record of the previous set. Repeat these two instructions by the `SFLPAG` size of the subfile. That gives you the `EXGDAT` key at the top of the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

The key that everyone is missing is a DDS keyword: `SFLRCDNBR[([CURSOR] [*TOP])]`

This keyword tells which subfile page to display when the screen is written. Look it up in the IBM manual https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=80-sflrcdnbr-subfile-record-number-keyword-display-files. there is an example of how to use it there, but the high level fly by is that you would count subfile records when you load it, and find the record specified by the find/position to field, and then put that value into the field before you do the write to the subfile control record. If you don't have a value in the position to field, you should load this field with the previous top record number, or 1.

For completeness, the previous top record number can be found in the display file feedback area.

If you can have errors on the subfile, the logic can get a bit complicated, so you might want to put the position subfile logic into a subprocedure because you will want to process errors before you process the field positioning logic. I have found the best precedence is:

1. The first subfile line with an error
2. The position to field
3. The top field in the subfile from the previous input operation
4. 1